# Indirect Group Membership with Keycloak and oauth2-proxy

Tags: freeipa, keycloak

I'm using `oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy` with Keycloak-oidc provider for authentication for some pods in my Kubernetes cluster.

I can specify which groups are allowed to access a resource using the `--allowed-group` argument such as below

```
- --allowed-group="/vm-users/vm-editors/vm-admins"
```

Which restricts login to members of the `vm-admins` group.

But when I set it to  `/vm-users/vm-editors` to login, I'm no longer allowed, as I have an indirect membership to `vm-editors` (It's set in FreeIPA, the user federation for keycloak, so that members of the `vm-admins` group are also members of the `vm-editors` group).

I've tried `/vm-users/vm-editors`, `/vm-users/vm-editors*`, `/vm-users/vm-editors/*`; none of which work.

Is there a way to handle implicit/indirect group membership in this instance?

Comment: did you ever get this working? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @kaiffeetasse no, but I haven't looked into it in the past 12 months.  Back then, I just switched to using Roles instead of groups and mapped the groups I needed to roles.